# Ansible : Must install the sshpass program

Tags: ansible, sshpass

Ansible command:

```
ansible all -m module-name -o  -e "ansible_user=username ansible_password=password"
```

Giving following error :

> host-ip | FAILED! => {"msg": "to use the 'ssh' connection type with passwords, you must install the sshpass program"}

Answer (score 5):

- Install sshpass:
  `apt-get update
  apt-get- install sshpass`
- if not This error can solved by  exporting environment variable.
                `export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False`
- If not try to create a file ansible.cfg in your current folder with the following contents:

  `[defaults]
  host_key_checking = false`

Comment: as the msg suggested... installing sshpass solves the issue.